# Emacs 23.3.1 fixedsys font issue

Tags: emacs, fonts, truetype, emacs23

1. I have downloaded the [Fixedsys.TTF](https://web.archive.org/web/20140429233048/http://www.moviecorner.de/en/font-fixedsys-ttf/fixedsys-download.html) font.
2. I have moved the font into the /usr/share/fonts/truetype directory.
3. I have opened Emacs and navigated to Options > Set Default Font... and selected 
   FixedsysTTF and specified Monospaced and size 11. I then used Options > Save Options.
4. I have noticed in my .emacs file:

   ```
   '(default ((t (:stipple nil :background "#232323"
    :foreground "#e6e1de" :inverse-video nil :box nil
    :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil
    :slant normal :weight semi-bold :height 110
    :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "FixedsysTTF"))))
   ```
5. I do some work in Emacs and close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.
6. I then reopen Emacs and it does not produce the same font. Rather, if I follow step 2. again I find that Emacs has defaulted to Monospace Regular 10. Although the font that is actually shown is not even Monospace Regular 10.
7. In order to correct this situation I am required to manually follow step 2. again and then everything is fine until I exit and startup again.

My question is whether or not there is a simple fix for this? Or, what lisp functions are being called in the background when I do step 2 so I can just hack the .emacs file to forcefully load fixedsys.

PS: I did try the font [Fixedsys Excelsior](http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/), which is perfect BUT for the fact that in said version of Emacs (that is not to say that this happens in ONLY said version, but I am restricted to 23.3.1) the 'A' character causes the proceeding character to overlap the 'A'. However, this version of Fixedsys does not cause a problem with Emacs, and it remembers the font on exiting and the re-opening. Therefore, it is either: correct the situation with the overlapping 'A', or get the other version of Fixedsys (the one linked in step 1) to work. I do actually prefer Fixedsys Excelsior, but I cannot live with an overlapping 'A'. FYI, when I use Fixedsys Excelsior I get the following in my .emacs file:

```
'(default ((t (:stipple nil :background "#232323"
:foreground "#e6e1de" :inverse-video nil :box nil
:strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal
:weight normal :height 117 :width normal :foundry "unknown"
:family "Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01"))))
```

Again, the font is downloaded from the Fixedsys Excelsior link above and then the TTF moved into /usr/share/fonts/truetype.

Can someone help sort out either of these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to solve this issue:

1. [Downloaded this modified version of FixedSYS](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/12984600/FSEX300-L.ttf)
2. Moved to /usr/share/fonts/truetype
3. Injected:
   `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01-L-12")` into my .emacs file

Answer (score -1):

Just to let you know, your links to Fixedsys.TTF font are pointing to a video site with questionable credentials.

- Chris